# Sort Numbers after Letters in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to sort Letters first and followed by numbers like below:

[Austria , France , Germany , 101110 , 124563]

This is what i have tried:

```
obj.sort((a,b) => a.text > b.text ? 1 : -1)
```

But it is sorting numbers first and then letters.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution like you want to sort string at the first portion of array and numbers at the last of array, just make sure that you are following this procedure.

- Never compare a string with a number.
- If both `a and b are string` or `both are numbers` just compare both with `a > b` and return 1 or -1 depending on the result of comparision.
- The last `else` block corresponds to the **comparision between a number and a string**. The return value determines the location of the numbers in the array. If either one of them is not a number, **return -1 or 1 depending on the requirement**. Since you want the numbers at the end of your array, `return -1` if the value is not a number. If you send 1 instead, the numbers will take the first posion in he output array.

```js
const data = [101110 , 124563 , 'France' , 'Austria', 'Germany'];
const output = data.sort((a,b) => {
  if (
      (isNaN(a) && isNaN(b)) || (!isNaN(a) && !isNaN(b))
  ) {
    // Both are strings
    // OR
    // Both are numbers
    return a > b ? 1 : -1;
  }
  else {
    // One of them is a number
    return isNaN(a) ? -1 : 1;
  }
});
console.log(output);
```

**Much Simplified version**

```js
const data = [101110, 'France', 'Austria', 124563, 'Germany'];
const checkOfSamePattern = (a, b) => (isNaN(a) && isNaN(b)) || (!isNaN(a) && !isNaN(b));
const output = data.sort((a, b) => checkOfSamePattern(a, b) ? a > b ? 1 : -1 : isNaN(a) ? -1 : 1);
console.log(output);
```